# FriendlyID with overridable tree-path slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, ancestry

I'm currently using Ancestry to manage a model structured as a tree, though the exact implementation of the tree doesn't really matter.

Given a model with the following properties:

```rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  attr_accessor :name :slug, :url_path 

  has_ancestry
  acts_as_list scope: :ancestry

  friendly_id METHOD, use: %i[slugged finders]
end
```

Where `slug` is either user-specified, and `url_path` is the full friendly_id of the `Item`, which is a combination of the `slug`s for all ancestral items joined with `/`

e.g. `/foo/bar/baz` would point to an item with a slug of `baz` which has ancestors with the slugs `foo` and `bar`

I've tried the following:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId

    friendly_id :path, use: %i[slugged finders]

    acts_as_list scope: :ancestry, top_of_list: 0

    has_ancestry

    def path
        :slug if ancestry.nil?
        (ancestors.collect(&:slug) << slug).join('/')
    end
end
```

However, when given the same `foo => [bar => baz]` items, the result is `foo-bar-baz` rather than `foo/bar/baz` -- How do I get my URL path to match the tree location with `/` separators?